# Solving equation in 3D

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, eigenvalues

How I can solve the equation in 3D domain?
According to the following post, I encounter an error when I run the program.
Any help would be graet!

**This section should be considered as a continuous program to avoid any possible errors**

Comment: "ImplicitRegion[surf, {{x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}}]" incorrectly defined. "surf" should be a condition.

Comment: "surf" is a vector function of u and v. However, Implicite Region needs a condition, e.g.ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 1, {x, y}]

Comment: Can you please specify explicitly the error that you get? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I assume "tours structure" means "torus surface". For this I would use a parameterized torus in cart. coord. Toroidal coordinates make this unnecessary complicated.
E.g.

```
r1 = 1; r2 = 2;
reg = ParametricRegion[{(r2 + r1 Cos[phi]) Cos[
      tau], (r2 + r1 Cos[phi]) Sin[tau], 
    r1 Sin[phi]}, {{phi, -Pi, Pi}, {tau, -Pi, Pi}}];
Region@reg
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! Does this solve the OP’s issue? Is it possible to show this? Thank you :)

Comment: There are syntax errors: "Module[{u, x, y, z, t, pde, dirichletCondition,..." has no closing bracket.  "{eigenValues, evIF, mesh}];" has no opening bracket, where does it belong?

Comment: Still syntax errors. Please copy it back to your machine and check.

Comment: I now executes. But it aborts because a lack of memory. I  have 32 GB.

Comment: The size of the problem makes it difficult. I think it will help to first solve a 2D problem or even a 1D problem and learn from this how to do it